# Object variable not set by looping through NotesViewNavigator

Tags: lotusscript

I try to loop through all ViewEntries in a view. After looping to some documents I get the error message "Object variable not set" when I want to set the "docOrder" document.

Debugging of the code shows that there are deletion stubs of documents in the ViewNavigator (no idea why?). When a deletion stub is in place the error message appears.

Here a code snippet of the LS-Script Agent:

```
 Call vwDelete.Refresh()
 vwDelete.AutoUpdate = False
 Set navOrders = vwDelete.createViewNav()
 Set veOrder = navOrders.getFirstDocument()

 While Not veOrder Is Nothing
    Set docOrder = veOrder.Document
        //do something
    Set veOrder = navOrders.getNextDocument(veOrder)
 Wend
```

I know I can use an If-Statement to check if the "document is nothing" but I'm curious why there are deletion stubs in ViewNavigator. It is an index problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Are these documents being deleted while you are iterating through the view?

Comment: No, I mark the documents to delete them later.

Comment: What type is veOrder ? If it is a NotesDocument why the veOrder.Document in your while loop ?

Comment: veOrder is a NotesViewEntry.

Comment: what I mean is, is someone else deleting them while you are iterating through the view?

Comment: No, agent is scheduled during the night time and no other agent can delete/is deleting the documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for the `NotesViewEntry` class

> If a document is deleted after a ViewEntryCollection containing that document is created, the result of navigating to the deleted document will be a ViewEntry that can be used to navigate to the next entry, but nothing more. All of the properties or methods on this type of ViewEntry, except IsValid, will return an error. If you are sure that none of the documents in a ViewEntryCollection have been deleted, you don't need to check this property; otherwise, it should be checked.

You don't want to check against `is nothing`.  You want to check `if vOrder.isValid()`.

Comment: ok, I check if vOrder.isValid(). The problem is that I'm sure that none of the documents in the ViewEntryCollection have been deleted. And from the documentation I don't have to check this property. I don't understand why the deleted documents (deletion stubs) are in the ViewNavigator.

Comment: Because the navigator is reading the view index, and they are in the index. The doc is misleading.  When using a view navigator, you should always assume that there might be deletion stubs there.

Comment: Thx Richard for your help. I modify my code and check if the ViewEntry "isValid()".